# typeerror: this.notificationeventservice.shownotification.subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

componenet file

```
ngOnInit(): void {
 this.subscribeNotification();
}
subscribeNotification {
  this.notificationEventService.showNotification.subscribe((data: NotificationData) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

Service file

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class NotificationEventService {
   public notificationCounter = 0;

   showNotification = new EventEmitter();

   notifySuccess(message: string) {
   const data = { type: 'banner', severity: 'success', discreet: false, text: message };
   this.showNotification.emit(data);
}
 }
```

spec file for component

```
const notificationEventServiceStub = () => ({
  showNotification: ()  => ({ subscribe: f => f({}) })
});
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
  providers: [{ provide: NotificationEventService, useFactory: notificationEventServiceStub}]
});
describe('ngOnInit', () => {
it('makes expected calls', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'subscribeNotification').and.callThrough();
  component.ngOnInit();
  expect(component.subscribeNotification).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
});
```

once I am spy on this ngOnInit function I am getting

TypeError: this.notificationEventService.showNotification.subscribe is not a function

Comment: You should be spying on the `subscribe` method of `EventEmitter`, **not** the `EventEmitter` object.

Comment: have you added the service in the provider of the module

Comment: Yes I have added actually this error I am getting in jasmine

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to do this you can use behaviourSubject rxjs and subscribe to it.
To change its value you have to use next() method instead of emit() method that's it you are good to go.
Here is an example of how to use Behaviour Subject RXJS [Reference Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-behaviour-subject-example)

> Hope this helps, Happy Coding :)

Comment: Is it not possible with event emmiteer?